# Launch python script with abaqus commands

Tags: python, command, abaqus

I have a command file (.cmd) which I use to launch Abaqus command line windows. Then, I use the command 'abaqus python create_part.py' to launch python command inside Abaqus.

Now, I would like to use a python script to do that. I've tried the script below, but it is not able to locate the file. Where should the test.py file be located? And is it possible to call test.py from a certain location? My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess as sp 
abaqus_path = "C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abaqus.cmd" sp.call([abaqus_path, 'abaqus', 'python', 'create_part.py'])
```

If I type abaqus python create_part.py in Abaqus Command, it has no problems finding the file.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the error message, which you get after running the code above? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response! Nothing happens at all... There's no error message

Comment: Run the following script with three lines of code and let me know what you get: ```import subprocess as sp``` ```pythonFilePath = "C:\\Temp\\DirectoryWithThePythonScript\\"``` ```sp.check_output(['abaqus.bat', 'python', pythonFilePath + 'create_part.py'])```.

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed ABAQUS properly, `"C:\SIMULIA\Commands\"` should have been already included in the environmental variable "path", and you should be able to run `abaqus.bat` (my example) or `abaqus.cmd` command from every location.
However, you might have the problem with an insufficient path specification for the `*.py` file.

**Solution 1:** If you are in the ABAQUS/CAE where you have set the Working directory to the directory where `create_part.py` file is located and you are running your script from the Kernel Command Line Interface, your code should look like:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['abaqus.bat', 'python', 'create_part.py'])
```

**Solution 2:** If you are in the ABAQUS/CAE where you have NOT set the Working directory to the directory where `create_part.py` file is located and you are running your script from the Kernel Command Line Interface, your code should look like:

```
import subprocess as sp 
pythonFilePath = "C:\\Temp\\DirectoryWithThePythonScript\\"
sp.call(['abaqus.bat', 'python', pythonFilePath + 'create_part.py'])
```

Note that the Solution 2 is more general.

Comment: @kariln        Any success with my answer?